# Question seems doesn't require or ask for a tool recommendation but was closed as tool recommendation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045826) question is closed as tool recommendation currently. Even the score of the question is low, or even require closing, the OP seems doesn't mention about acquiring any external materials or tools suggestions to solve the problem.

(Actually I'm not saying this question is valid, just wonder the current close reason applied to it...)

Comment: This seems to a homework question in my opinion, what the OP is trying is like really basic. maybe it was interpreted as "find me a function/library that will do my homework question".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question had:

- 1 x primarily opinion-based
- 2 x off-topic → Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource
- 1 x off-topic → Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
- 1 x too broad

So the majority reason was "off-topic" and within that the majority was tool request - hence the banner displayed...